# Is there an ∞-categorical interpretation of the Quillen S⁻¹S construction?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, model-categories, algebraic-k-theory, infinity-categories

The Quillen S⁻¹S construction (not to be confused with the Quillen Q-construction or the Quillen plus-construction),
as defined by Grayson in *Higher algebraic K-theory: II* (page 219),
takes as an input a symmetric monoidal groupoid S
and produces a symmetric monoidal category S⁻¹S,
whose objects are pairs (s,s') of objects in S
and morphisms (s,s')→(t,t') are isomorphism classes of triples (A,A⊕s→t,A⊕s'→t').

**Has this construction been investigated ∞-categorically,
e.g., in the language of model categories?**

I cannot even find a reference in the literature that shows
that S⁻¹S represents (in the Thomason model structure) the homotopy group completion of S,
so any references on this matter will be appreciated.

Once we do know that S↦S⁻¹S is the homotopy group
completion functor, there is also the question
of interpreting it as a left (derived) Quillen functor
for some choice of a model structure on symmetric monoidal groupoids and (presumably) the Thomason model structure on categories.

A paper by Thomason (Beware the phony multiplication on Quillen's S⁻¹S) shows in particular
that one cannot have an inverse functor x↦−x on S⁻¹S
so that x⊕−x is naturally (strictly) isomorphic to 0.
However, this does not preclude other ∞-categorical interpretations of the S⁻¹S construction.

Comment: do you want to see $S\mapsto S^{-1}S$ as left adjoint or as homotopy left adjoint ? Would you be satisfied if you translate every thing in terms of $E_{\infty}$-spaces (since you have mentioned Thomason model structure).

Comment: @IliasAmrani: I might be wrong, but I think the implicit folklore understanding is that S⁻¹S computes the homotopy left adjoint.  I'll add “derived” to the post.  I will also be happy with an interpretation using group-like E_∞-spaces of any kind.

Comment: @IliasAmrani: I guess I misunderstood the intended meaning of “translate … E_∞-spaces”: showing that some other well-known formula for the homotopy group completion (e.g., ΩB) implements the homotopy group completion functor is not a part of the question.  I am interested exclusively in S⁻¹S, not some other construction.

Comment: No problem, that happens :). You wrote "I cannot $\mathbf{even}$ find a reference in the literature that shows that S⁻¹S represents (in the Thomason model structure) the homotopy group completion of S, so any references on this matter will be appreciated." That is why i concluded that you were asking also if this functor is homotopy left adjoint under hypothesis that you know that it represent complition...

Comment: @IliasAmrani: I now see where the misunderstanding comes from.  My intended meaning of “even” was that even if one does know that S⁻¹S is the homotopy group completion of S, there is still the question of which model structures to choose on both sides so that S⁻¹S preserves (acyclic) cofibrations (and hence is a left Quillen functor).

Comment: I am quite pessimistic about a positive answer to your question with such constraints :)

Comment: Hello, I am also learning this material. I don't know whether you have read Segal's paper [Categories and Cohomology Theories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/files/SegalCategoriesAndCohomologyTheories.pdf). It seems to me that the construction on page 304-305 of section 4 is closely related to $S^{-1}S$, which could be viewed as a kind of fibrant replacement. I cannot work out a precise argument for the moment.

Comment: @FrankScience: Yes, Quillen's S⁻¹S construction is an elaboration on this theme (and Segal credits Quillen for this section).  For special Γ-spaces this indeed produces a very special Γ-space, which is a fibrant replacement.

Comment: Here's a motivating example: let $S$ be the topological groupoid of finite-dimensional real inner-product spaces. The category $S^{-1}S$ (and not just its geometric realization) is used by [Sagave and Schlichtkrull](https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.4492), to construct certain graded orthogonal ring spectra. I think in other work they do the analogous thing for symmetric spectra. $\mathbb{Z}$-graded ring spectra are important -- related to power operations and log structures -- but surprisingly delicate, since $\mathbb{Z}$ is a _strictly_ symmetric monoidal category ($m+n \to n+m$ is the _identity_).

Comment: I have added an answer to another mathoverflow post that is very much related.
https://mathoverflow.net/a/462976/76299

To spare you the click: In the case of a symmetric monoidal groupoid, the S^-1 S construction is the unstraigthening of the diagonal action of S on S x S. This characterization can be completely generalized in the setting of infinity-categories